# does console exe files created by matlab need MCR

Tags: matlab, user-interface, console, exe

I wrote an application (GUI) in Matlab and I want to distribute it as a console exe file, does the user need to install MCR?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes

I stole a nice answer from [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7519):

> When using the MATLAB Compiler to compile MATLAB code into a
>   standalone executable, you do need to install the MCR because the
>   generated code calls into these runtime libraries. Also, you can
>   package the MCR together with the executable and have it installed
>   automatically when the executable is run. If you are using deploytool,
>   you simply need to select "Add MCR" and "Embed the MCR in the package"
>   from the Package pane.
>
> Note that MATLAB Coder is the other product that actually allows you
>   to generate truly standalone C/C++ code from MATLAB code (without any
>   need for additional libraries like the MCR). However, it supports only
>   a limited subset of the MATLAB language.